# Cannot add foreign key constrain on delete cascade

Tags: laravel, laravel-7, laravel-migrations

I am trying to create a cascade on two migrations:

```
Schema::create('product_product_attribute',
    function ($table) {
        $table->bigIncrements('id');
        $table->bigInteger('product_id')->unsigned();
        $table->bigInteger('product_attribute_id')->unsigned();
        $table->boolean('custom')->nullable();
        $table->string('title')->nullable();
        $table->string('unit')->nullable();
        $table->string('type')->nullable();
        $table->text('value')->nullable();
        $table->float('price')->nullable();
        $table->bigInteger('position')->nullable();
        $table->foreign('product_id', 'pp_id')->references('id')
            ->on('products')->onDelete('cascade');
        $table->timestamps();
    });


Schema::create('product_attributes', function ($table) {
    $table->bigIncrements('id');
    $table->string('title');
    $table->string('unit')->nullable();
    $table->string('type');
    $table->float('price')->nullable();
    $table->nestedSet();
    $table->foreign('id')->references('product_attribute_id')
        ->on('products')->onDelete('cascade');
    $table->timestamps();
});
```

So what it is supposed to do:

If the Product that contains an attribute, both, the attribute and the pivot table for the attribute should be cascading.

This fails with:

> Illuminate/Database/QueryException with message 'SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1215 Cannot add foreign key constraint (SQL: alter table `product_attributes` add constraint `product_attributes_id_foreign` foreign key (`id`) references `products` (`product_attribute_id`) on delete cascade)'

Where did I do my mistake?

Comment: Shouldn't he foreign logic be set in the product_product_attribute table? Same as you did you the product_id/pp_id? (does it work without the onDelete(cascade)?)

Comment: Assume you have `products`,  `product_attributes`,  `product_product_attribute` tables. Do you want, if a `product` is deleted then associated `product_attributes` and `product_product_attribute` will be cascaded? Would you please give the schema of `products` table?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to add the foreign key reference on the primary key of `product_attributes` table and wrong reference column. The correct reference to the `products` table

```
$table->unsignedBigInteger('product_id');
$table->foreign('product_id')->references('id')
            ->on('products')->onDelete('cascade');
```

The full schema of `product_attributes` table is

```
Schema::create('product_attributes', function ($table) {
        $table->bigIncrements('id');
        $table->string('title');
        $table->string('unit')->nullable();
        $table->string('type');
        $table->float('price')->nullable();
        $table->nestedSet();
        $table->unsignedBigInteger('product_id');
        $table->foreign('product_id')->references('id')
            ->on('products')->onDelete('cascade');
        $table->timestamps();
    });
```